# Override a list element?

Tags: list, prolog

Is there a way to add an element to a list, without caring if it already exists and the list still not containing duplicates?

Comment: Your context is not particulairly clear. Language..?

Comment: Alright I don't know anything about prolog, but I would think of using an array. Arrays exist like [0,1,0,1] (whatever language) right :-) Forgive me if my comment is useless.

Comment: if you don't care whether it exists and add it in, and it did exist already in the list, then you end up with a duplicate. Contradiction in your terms.

Comment: @WillNess not if there is a default override operator in prolog, which checks whether the element already exists (so the user doesn't have to) before adding.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for efficiency there are better data structures than lists, ready to use in SWI-Prolog. In particular, your use case fits on [add_nb_set](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.13%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/nb_set.html%27%29%29)(+Key, !Set, ?New).

Argument `New` controls the behaviour WRT duplicates: you should use `true` for don't care.
Argument `Set` must be 'allocated' with `empty_nb_set(Set)`

**edit**: I apologize, argument `Set` must be a free var for `don't care behaviour`, like for instance `add_nb_set(Key, Set, _)`, as evident for the documentation page....

Answer (score 2):

You could first check whether the item is contained in the list and add it only if it's not.
For example:

```
add_no_duplicates(List, Item, NList):-
  member(Item, List) -> NList=List ; NList=[Item|List].
```

Test:

```
?- add_no_duplicates([a,b,c],d,L).
L = [d, a, b, c].
?- add_no_duplicates([a,b,c,d],d,L).
L = [a, b, c, d].
```

Note that add_no_duplicates/3 as written needs the input list (List) to be instantiated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want to implement a set; check the l[ist manual page](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.12%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/lists.html%27%29%29) for set operations.
It appears that there is no add but there is [union/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=union/3) so you can add elements by intersecting with a set of the new element (intersection([NewEl], OldSet, NewSet). Note that you dont have to convert a list to a set (a list is a set as long as it doesnt have duplicates; list_to_set/2 just eliminates them).

Now if you have a list with duplicates and you want sometimes to add an element the way you stated you will have to implement something yourself.

Comment: the OP wants union, not intersection of {the singleton with a new element} and the old set. The intersection would just be empty, or that singleton - in case the set contained that new element. `ord_union/2` would seem to fit the bill, provided the OP maintains their lists ordered, always. http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=ord_union%2f3

Comment: @WillNess indeed, my mistake; fixed